# Concurrent get and put rest calls, how to implement

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have array containing 100 records containing one field ID, 
so i need to take IDs from above array and do GET rest call to fetch details, then once information is there i need to make PUT call.

currently its synchronous behavior, i.e requests goes like below.
Record 1 - GET 
Record 1 - PUT
Record 2 - GET
Record 2 - PUT
Record 3 - GET
Record 3 - PUT
and so on.

what i want to achive is, rest calls in chunks lets say chunk size is 3, so rest calls should be like.
Record 1 - GET
Record 2 - GET
Record 3 - GET
Record 1 - PUT
Record 2 - PUT
Record 3 - PUT

then next chunk of records

Comment: this seem like too many calls.. can't you change you api so that accepts lists in order to reduce your calls to 2?

Comment: no we have requirement like that only, thats why? is there any way we can use mergeMap with concurrent rest calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `buffer` incoming values with `bufferCount()`, then `forkJoin` calls, flatten stream and repeat again for next calls:

```
const sub = source.pipe(
  bufferCount(2),
  concatMap(ids => forkJoin(ids.map(id => ajax.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)))),
  map(data => data.map(res => res.response.id)),
  concatMap(ids => forkJoin(ids.map(id => ajax.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)))),
  map(data => data.map(res => res.response.title)),
)
```

I made a [DEMO to play with](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-phmsqh?file=index.ts)